# NodeJS - Use object properties on the receiving end

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a small helper file to split (and re-use) some of my code.

It comes down to this:

```
const actorObject = new Actor(firstname, lastname, role)
service.registerActor(actorObject)
```

then in my service

```
registerActor(actorInfo) {
   return connector.publish('actorTable', actorInfo.name, converter.toHex(actorInfo))
     .then(result => result)
     .catch(error => error)
```

The problem that I have in my IDE (vs code) is that when I do "actorInfo." I don't see the actor properties, because it enters the method as an "any". I tried multiple ways to get the actor properties across, but I can't seem to get it to work. I remember I solved a similar problem fairly easy in Typescript a while ago, but I can't get it to work in NodeJS. It's only 1 property right now, but further along in my project I'm going to have objects with 10+ properties that will be used like this one way or another.

I fixed it with the following:

```
registerActor(actorInfo) {
   const newActor = new Actor(actorInfo)
   return connector.publish('actorTable', newActor .name, converter.toHex(newActor))
     .then(result => result)
     .catch(error => error)
```

but it feels wrong to create yet another actor object. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: may be http://usejsdoc.org/ can help you? I'm not sure about supporting of JSDoc in VS Code.
P.S. why do you do like this `catch(error => error)` - in case error this will return `error` as regular value from promise the same as `.then(result => result)`?

Comment: What IDE are you using?